# Converting paired table to binary table

Tags: python

i wouldn't be posting this if i didn't do extensive research in attempt to find the answer. Alas, I have not been able to find any such answer. I have a paired dataset that looks something like this:

```
PERSON, ATTRIBUTE
person1, a
person1, b
person1, c
person1, d
person2, c
person2, d
person2, x
person3, a
person3, b
person3, e
person3, f
```

What I want to do is: 1) drop attributes that don't appear more than 10 times, 2) turn it into a binary table that would look something like this:

```
          a     b     c
person1   1     1     1  
person2   0     0     1  
person3   1     1     0
```

So far, I have put together a script to drop the attributes that only appear 10 times; however, it is painfully slow as it has to go through each attribute, determine its frequency and find the corresponding x and y values to append to new variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from collections import Counter
import time

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer='sample.csv',
    sep=',') 

x = df.ix[:, 1].values
y = df.ix[:, 0].values

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

counter = Counter(x)

start_time = time.time()

for each in counter:
    if counter[each]>=10:
        for i, j in enumerate(x):
            if j==each:
                print "Adding position:" + str(i)
                x_vals.append(each)
                y_vals.append(y[i])


print "Time took: %s" %(time.time()-start_time)
```

I would love some help in 1) finding a faster way to match attributes that appear more than 10 times and appending the values to new variables.

OR

2) An alternative method entirely to get the final binary table. I feel like converting a paired table to a binary table is probably a common occurrence in the data world, yet i couldnt find any code, module etc that could help with doing that.

Thanks a million!

Comment: I feel like `itertools.groupby` will be a big help here, but I don't have the time to put anything together at the moment. Construct a set of groups like `{'person1': [('person1', 'a'), 'person2', 'b'), ...] }` then only add the row if there are more than 10 items and mark each `df[groupname][item.split(',')[1]] = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably add a dummy column and then call `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"PERSON": ["p1", "p2", "p3"] * 10, "ATTRIBUTE": np.random.choice(["a","b","c","d","e","f","x"], 30)})
>>> df.head()
  ATTRIBUTE PERSON
0         d     p1
1         b     p2
2         x     p3
3         b     p1
4         f     p2
>>> df["count"] = 1
>>> p = df.pivot_table(index="PERSON", columns="ATTRIBUTE", values="count", 
                       aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
>>> p
ATTRIBUTE  a  b  c  d  e  f  x
PERSON                        
p1         1  3  1  1  1  0  3
p2         2  1  1  2  1  2  1
p3         0  4  1  1  2  0  2
```

And then we can select only the attributes with more than 10 occurrences (here 5, from my example):

```
>>> p.loc[:,p.sum() >= 5]
ATTRIBUTE  b  x
PERSON         
p1         3  3
p2         1  1
p3         4  2
```